# I am getting an 403 error when I am trying to access an api through my app

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-volley, http-status-code-403

I am a bit new to android development. I was using an api form newsapi.org and every time I am getting
a some thing like this while api call[See the last line in run log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AQQ2.png)

Can any body help me with this, like is there might be a problem from my end or some thing else?...Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried this with postman?

Comment: you've posted your api key in the picture you've provided, so others can now also use this key and (if it's a paid for key) you will receive the bill for it. don't include these types of keys online, they're meant to be private for a reason

Comment: @a_local_nobody No, bro its not a paid api key!...But thanks bro I will still take care from next time!

Answer (score 0):

The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code that means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason and  you don't have permission to access [directory] on this server. I saw your attached image and I think maybe your api key is out dated.